# how to change the distance of plotshape from the candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to be able to specify the distance of my plotshape.
I found this [post](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/annotations/Plotting_shapes_chars_and_arrows.html) related but there is no useful answer there.

so basically I want to be able to specify the distance of the arrow from the top of the candle, so later I be able to plot multiple arrow on the top of the candle.
As an example:

[image]

or

[image]

or

[image]

I want to be able to do this eventually

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `plotshape()` for that, set your `location` argument to `location.absolute`. Then adjust the price for position.

You can also use `labels` for that.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

atr = ta.atr(10)
pos1 = high + (1 * atr)
pos2 = high + (2 * atr)
pos3 = high + (3 * atr)
c = barstate.islast

plotshape(c ? pos1 : na , "One", shape.xcross, location.absolute, color.red, 0, "One")
plotshape(c ? pos2 : na , "Two", shape.diamond, location.absolute, color.yellow, 0, "Two")
plotshape(c ? pos3 : na , "Three", shape.square, location.absolute, color.green, 0, "Three")
```

[image]